# Unity3D - JsonUtility returns empty string

Tags: unity, c#, serialization, json

i have the problem that when I convert an instance of highscores through JsonUtility.ToJson the value of my value of it is always {"highscoreEntryList":[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]}...

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class HighScoreTable : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Transform entryContainer;
    private Transform entryTemplate;
    private List<HighScoreEntry> highScoreEntries;
    private List<Transform> highScoreEntryTransformList;
    private void Awake()
    {
        entryContainer = transform.Find("HighScoreEntryContainer");
        entryTemplate = entryContainer.Find("HighScoreEntryTemp");

        entryTemplate.gameObject.SetActive(false);

        highScoreEntries = new List<HighScoreEntry>() 
        {
            new HighScoreEntry { Score = 9999, Name = "T1"} ,
            new HighScoreEntry { Score = 9282, Name = "T2"} ,
            new HighScoreEntry { Score = 9942, Name = "T3"} ,
            new HighScoreEntry { Score = 2419, Name = "t4"} ,
            new HighScoreEntry { Score = 2390, Name = "t5"} ,
            new HighScoreEntry { Score = 9282, Name = "t7"} ,
            new HighScoreEntry { Score = 2918, Name = "t6"} ,
            new HighScoreEntry { Score = 4921, Name = "t8"} ,
            new HighScoreEntry { Score = 1318, Name = "t9"} ,
            new HighScoreEntry { Score = 8818, Name = "t10"} ,
            new HighScoreEntry { Score = 9231, Name = "t11"} ,
        };

        highScoreEntryTransformList = new List<Transform>();
        highScoreEntries.Sort((first, second) => second.Score.CompareTo(first.Score));

        foreach (var highScoreEntry in highScoreEntries)
            CreateHighScoreEntry(highScoreEntry, entryContainer, highScoreEntryTransformList);

        Highscores highscores = new Highscores {highscoreEntryList = highScoreEntries };
        string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(highscores);
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("highscoreTable", json);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
        Debug.Log(PlayerPrefs.GetString("highscoreTable"));
    }

    private void CreateHighScoreEntry(HighScoreEntry highScoreEntry, Transform container, List<Transform> transformlist)
    {
        float tempHeight = 40f;
        Transform entryTransform = Instantiate(entryTemplate, container);
        RectTransform entryRectTransform = entryTransform.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        entryRectTransform.anchoredPosition = new Vector2(0, -tempHeight * transformlist.Count);
        entryTransform.gameObject.SetActive(true);

        entryTransform.Find("posText").GetComponent<Text>().text = "" + (transformlist.Count + 1);
        entryTransform.Find("scoreText").GetComponent<Text>().text = "" + highScoreEntry.Score;
        entryTransform.Find("nameText").GetComponent<Text>().text = "" + highScoreEntry.Name;

        transformlist.Add(entryTransform);

    }


    private class Highscores
    {
        public List<HighScoreEntry> highscoreEntryList;
    }

    [Serializable]
    private class HighScoreEntry
    {
        public int Score { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My List property is public and i also tried to write [SerializeField] over it.

Answer (score 2):

JSONUtility can serialize *fields*, but it can not serialize *properties*. As [the documentation of `[SerializeField]`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeField.html) says:

> The serialization system can do the following:
>
> - CAN serialize public non-static fields (of serializable types)
> - CAN serialize nonpublic non-static fields marked with the SerializeField attribute.
> - CANNOT serialize static fields.
> - **CANNOT serialize properties.**

So how do we solve this problem? The most simple solution would be to get rid of the `{ get; set; }` parts in `class HighScoreEntry`.

```
[Serializable]
private class HighScoreEntry
{
    public int Score;
    public string Name;
}
```

Whether those fields are raw public fields or properties with trivial getters and setters shouldn't really change anything in this *particular* case. But if you really want to use properties in a serializable object for some reason, then you have to use getters and setters which encapsulate private fields marked with the `[SerializeField]` attribute:

```
[Serializable]
private class HighScoreEntry
{
    [SerializeField] private int score;
    public int Score {  get { return this.score; }
                        set { this.score = value; } }


    [SerializeField] private string name;
    public int Name {  get { return this.name; }
                       set { this.name = value; } }
}
```